# How to get around menu limit in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have menu in Wordpress by name "Category-menu", there is 20 items. 
When I add new category in the end as a child element, and click button save. Not saved.

max_input_vars: 10000 value

My hosting do not use: Suhosin.

Help me.

[image]

Comment: are you getting an error response when saving?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs on [wordpress.se].

Comment: The most interesting are no mistakes

Comment: You can ask this question also on StackOverflow RU, what could be more convenient to you.

Comment: Problem could be in plugins or your theme. Try to deactivate all plugins one by one, then change theme to standard, let say twentyseventeen.This will help to localize the source of error.